# SyntaxError: ('future feature unicode_literals is not defined)

Tags: python

I have the following the python code (helloworld.py)

```
from faker import Factory
class HelloWorld:

fake = None
name = None

def __init__(self):
    self.fake = Factory.create()
    self.name = ""

def getName(self):
    self.name = self.fake.name()
    return self.name
```

I'm trying to access the module from Java and my Java code is as below

```
PythonInterpreter interpreter = new PythonInterpreter();

interpreter.exec("import sys\nsys.path.append('C:\\Python27\\Lib\\site-packages')\n" +
                "sys.path.append('C:\\Python27\\Lib\\site-packages\\helloworld')\nfrom helloworld import HelloWorld");


PyInstance wrapper = (PyInstance)interpreter.eval("instance = HelloWorld" + "(" + ")");  

PyObject result = wrapper.invoke("instance.getName()");

String realResult = (String) result.__tojava__(String.class);
```

But I'm getting the error

```
SyntaxError: ('future feature unicode_literals is not defined', ('C:\\Python27\\Lib\\site-packages\\faker\\generator.py', 1, 6, ''))
```

where generator.py uses that module

```
generator.py
---------------

from __future__ import unicode_literals
```

I'm using Python 2.7. Should I try with the newer version of Python here?

Any suggestion please.

The Python interpreter is configured with Python 2.7 (Eclipse snapshot below)

[image: Python interpreter setup in eclipse]

## EDIT

Yes, I could import unicode_literals from **future** when executed from IDLE.

[image: Snapshot from IDLE]

Thanks @Martijn Pieters

The interpreter is actually using 2.1 as I can see with sys.version.

Now how can I change that to use 2.7 instead?

Comment: Are you 100% certain that `PythonInterpreter` invokes Python 2.7?

Comment: yes, added the eclipse snapshot

Comment: When you run `C:\Python27\python.exe` on the command line does it print the 2.7 header? Does it work if you issue `from __future__ import unicode_literals`?

Comment: yes, it does work when I issue it from the Python Shell

Comment: @user1356042: I'd try using `interpreter.exec("import sys; print sys.version")` instead

Comment: ohh...it showing 2.1...How can I change that to 2.7..?

Comment: you are using jython; not cpython.  That's okay, but finding the right version may not be obvious, since it was behind CPython for a long time; and jython2.7 is still in beta.  Try downloading a build directly from the [jython site](http://www.jython.org/) and adding it to your classpath?

Comment: solved...I was using Jython 2.1, So added Jython 2.7 and worked. Thanks everyone..!!!